# what does the period (.) do when using rsync

Tags: command-line, bash, rsync

Are the two commands below interchangeable? Does it matter whether I use the `.` or not?

```
sudo rsync -aXS /home/ /media/home/
sudo rsync -aXS /home/. /media/home/.
```

I know that the period `.` means the following in the `rsync` context:

`.` refers to the current directory

`..` refers to the parent directory

Answer (score 4):

One  usage of `.` in rsync is to limit the amount of path information that is sent as implied directories for each path you specify.

```
rsync -avR /src/path/to/dir/./file /target/
```

creates `file` in `/target` while:

```
rsync -avR /src/path/to/dir/file /target/
```

would creates `/src/path/to/dir/file` in `/target`.

---

The other usage is when you are using `rsync` with `-d` option:

```
rsync -d /boot /target
```

will copy the `boot` into `/target` while: `rsync -d /boot/ /target` or: `rsync -d /boot/. /target` would copy the contents of `/boot` into `/target`.

As I can see, it your situation it doesn't make any differences.

[rsync documentation](https://download.samba.org/pub/rsync/rsync.html)